# datagridview event causing datagridview to no fill up properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, datagridview, datagrid

Both of these functions are working fine, one should fill up datagrid with data, the other, should be triggered when i select a row from the first datagrid. But for some reason the second function is causing datagrid to fill just one row of data.

```
private void fillDataGrid(DataGridView dg, string query) {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                oda.Fill(dt);
                **dg.DataSource = dt;**
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

This function is called when i load the form, and it is working fine on its own. But when the next function is causing some kind of problem and i don't know why.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String s = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            String upit = "select dn.* from detaljinarudzbe dn, narudzba n where dn.nid = n.nid and n.jmbg = " + s + "";
            fillDataGrid(dataGridView2, upit);
        }
```

It is working fine, but i get just one row in first datagridview. And expection says

> system.argument out of range exception:must be non negative and less
>   than the size of collection

Caused by the ** line in first method. I don't get why is the event causing this problem. when i use the second function on a button it is working fine.

Comment: I put in datagridview properties that only fullrow can be selected and it works, but the selectionchangedevent still causes the the error message. Is there  better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try (I using SQL Server) : attention check **SelectedRows[0]** by **SelectedRows.Count**

```
private void fillDataGrid(DataGridView dg, string query) {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        SqlDataAdapter oda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oda.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
            dg.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            String s = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            String upit = "Select * from CARD_NO where CT_ID = " + s + "";
            fillDataGrid(dataGridView2, upit);
        }

    }
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillDataGrid(dataGridView1, "Select * from CARD_TYPE");
    }
```